# Prevent generation of log files from a cronjob

Tags: cron

Below image link shows the cron job that we have setup which is creating the log file in the root every minute.

[image: click here to view cronjob]

I am on a shared server and I do not wish to have the log files or else it will load up the server very quickly. It creates the files such as schedulesms.1, schedulesms.2, etc and so on.

Can you please provide me a way to ensure it does not create the log files.

Answer (score 0):

The files you are seeing are not `cron` but `wget` output. The most common use of `wget` output is fetching web pages on disk.

Whilst you are redirecting `stdin` and `stdout`, you did not account for the `wget` usage of saving web pages.

If you just want to access that URL, you may ask `wget` not to save any output with the `-q` quiet option.

Per `man wget`:

> -q
>   --quiet    Turn off Wget's output.

I would also prefer not having a cron job on a shared server running every minute, and would run at the minimum every 5 minutes, as in:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q http://yoururl > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I got this from my host wget -O /dev/null http://url and now it is not creating any more files and the cron job is also running. Thanks for your answer @Rui F Ribeiro though.